# VPN works on some site but not on some others

Tags: networking, vpn

I have recently started using Ubuntu Mate 17.04. I have established a VPN connection having `Point-to-Point Tunneling (PPTP)` type and it had been working very good. I have recently encountered the problem of not being able to open `facebook` or `youtube` pages (although being able to view other websites that are filtered by my ISP), and I don't know what wrong must have happened. Could you please tell me how I could find where my problem might be and how to fix it? 
Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After searching the web as much as possible, I found some other posts by other people having similar problems. And there were also all different sorts of answers given.
Among all those answers, I was introduced to the concept of `MTU`. I decided to give it a try changing the contents of /etc/network/interfaces by adding

> MTU 9000

to the end of my enp3s0 configurations, saving it and restarting Ubuntu to check if it has started working properly, and yes: it did start to work like a charm.
In case anyone out there is eager to know more about MTU he can find more here on wikipedia page:
[Maximum Transmission Unit](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_transmission_unit)

Comment: This is also worth to mention that this problem appears after the very first upgrade and after the restart we see it causing headaches for users. The default value of mtu would be 1500, and although after the upgrade this value did not change I had to make the system use my introduced value  as mentioned in the answer provided above.